# Extract the emotion from an audio voice signal

Tags: python, voice, emotion

I need to take the emotion from an audio voice signal.

**For example:** you send me a vocal message and you are happy because you have finally realized your dreams.
I'm in a church and i cannot listen the message, so I read the message and an
image like this :D or this :( tells me what you are feeling.

So I have to analyze the vocal message for knowing this feeling. How will `Linear Predictive Coding` help me to achieve this in python.

Note: I am currently using `audiolazy`.

Comment: Have you already read anything about this subject? I don't know much about it but I would probably start by reading some papers or existing tools to learn about it. Following, some links that might be helpful: [Paper](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1506/1506.05012.pdf); [Blog Post with References](http://www.seaandsailor.com/initial_representation.html); [Python package 1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/); [Python package 2](https://github.com/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis).

Comment: thank you thank you and still thank you...!!! great.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. You can check the package [pyAudioAnalyzer](https://github.com/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis)'s code to see how it is implemented and the references to the underlying papers. Or, just use the package itself.